# Python module (pyenv) installation not working

Tags: python, windows, command-line

Trying to install pyenv-win module according to the guide: https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/blob/master/README.md

But I'm a command prompt noob in Windows and so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I ran "pip install pyenv-win --target "%USERPROFILE%.pyenv" " which seemed to be successful.

But, running "[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PYENV',$env:USERPROFILE + ".pyenv\pyenv-win","User")" did not work. Clearly I'm not picking up what the README author is putting down.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to reopen a new terminal window. refreshenv didn't work as it said it did.

Comment: Same problem, how did you solved? A new terminal windows is a new command prompt? I did that and nothing change. Also what's 'refreshenv'? Thank you

Comment: Yes, just a new instance of the same command prompt. Sorry, I came from Mac so am used to calling it "terminal". 

refreshenv was a command that's supposed to refresh the environment and accomplish the same thing as opening a new window, but apparently didn't work as advertised. It's been a while so I don't remember all the details

Answer (score 1):

@DJB - It appears you are missing some backslashes. Try the following instead:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PYENV',$env:USERPROFILE + "\.pyenv\pyenv-win\","User")
```

**Edit**:

The missing backlashes could simply be because of how StackOverflow's editor handles backslashes (escape characters).

I would also recommend that you use Powershell to run this command instead of the CMD prompt, since that worked for me.